# terraform repeat server config for specific instances

Tags: terraform

Sorry for the question, I'm kinda new to terraform. I am working with a private cloud provider (so not AWS, Azure, GCP...)
I defined some servers in my module variables.tf

```
variable "server_config" {
  type = map(object({
    name                 = string
    memory_size_mib      = number
    num_vcpus_per_socket = string
    num_sockets          = number
    image_name           = string
    additional_disk_list = any
    disk_size_mib        = number
  }))
```

In my defaults I have 4 servers I always want to deploy with the names app, img, lb, db. Two of those servers could also be multiple. So I want a variable I can control this, like app_servers = 2. Now in my module with for_each I like to go through my 4 servers, in case I came across name=app or name=img I like to additionally repeat according to var.app_servers, so also the name will be adapted to app01, app02, app03 etc.
I already tried to discuss this with ChatGPT, but always feel misunderstood, so coming back to oldschool stack overflow. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems updating to ChatGPT-4 is worth it. I got now the following solution which seems to work as I would expect it:

```
locals {
  dynamic_servers = flatten([
    [for i in range(var.app_servers) : merge(var.server_config["app"], { "name" = format("app%02d", i+1) })],
    [for i in range(var.app_servers) : merge(var.server_config["img"], { "name" = format("img%02d", i+1) })],
    merge(var.server_config["lb"], { "name" = "lb" }),
    merge(var.server_config["db"], { "name" = "db" })
  ])
}

resource "your_server_resource" "this" {
  for_each = { for s in local.dynamic_servers : s.name => s }
```